# Iterate over all list of a site, and all subsites which type is events

Tags: list, calendar

I need to make a change to all calendars in the site.  We have a big hierarchy of sites and the calendar is enabled in all sites.

I have the code to make the change I need in one list.

```
SPWeb web = //get the SPWeb object from somewhere 
SPList list = web.Lists["CalendarName"]; 
var field = list.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkspaceLink]; 
field.Hidden = true; field.Update();
```

What I am missing here is the loop to iterave over all lists of all sites and 2nd, detect only the ones which type is calendar or event.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to iterate through every web, Personnaly I even think its bad.

Instead, use the SPSiteDataQuery class

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

// Query all Web sites in this site collection.
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";

//Ask for all lists created from the Calendar template.
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"106\" />";

DataTable dtResults = site.RootWeb.GetSiteData(query);
String[] columns = {"ListId"};
DataTable dtDistinctResults = new DataView(dtResults).ToTable(true, columns);

foreach (DataRow oRow in dtDistinctResults .Rows)
{
SPWeb oWeb = site.OpenWeb(new Guid(oRow["WebId"].ToString()));
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[new Guid(oRow["ListId"].ToString())];
//peprform your changes
}
```

This is a quick example. You should only open each web ONCE !
For example the dtDisctinctResults may contain 80 rows ( = 80 lists) but these 80 lists are on 4 sites. So you should only open SPWeb 4 times, not 80 times.
Since this has nothing to do with the question itselves, I leave this up to you.

To help you, I have quickly written a piece of code which would guide you in the right direction. I am not claiming this piece of code is written as it should be... http://pastie.org/3349098

This should work for you, more info on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx

PS: It might be possible that you need to assign more properties of the query class. here is my working example for tasks which are not completed:

```
SPSiteDataQuery oQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
oQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='107' />";
oQuery.Query = "<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='" + "Status" + "' /><Value Type='Text'>" + "Completed" + "</Value></Neq></Where>";
oQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
```

Above code will return all ListItems (which are not completed) in task lists

Comment: great solution, thx

Comment: really cool option. I didn't know it. :)

Comment: I haven't tested the performance of this solution vs iteration over all webs+lists. But my guess is this is alot quicker.

Comment: I've updated the code, since it contained some problems for this example

Comment: Frederik, I don't understand this - SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[new Guid(oRow["ListId"].ToString())];
It seems you works with lists from a single web.

Comment: You will need to "open" the SPWeb if you want to modify the SPList...

Comment: I've updated the answer, i forgot that line. Sorry

Comment: Ive added a link to pastie, with an approach which will  have better performance. Tho I've not tested it.

Comment: @FrederikP. Does it work for all site collections in the farm? Or I have to do this for each site collection?

Comment: I have no clue whether this works in the entire farm. I would guess NO. But not sure ...

Answer (score 0):

[SPSite.AllWebs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allwebs.aspx) collection is a plain collection of all webs in site collection. Note that you must dispose webs obtained from that collection. For each obtained SPWeb you can iterate through list via [SPWeb.Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.lists.aspx) property. You can filter lists by [SPList.BaseTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate.aspx) property - for calendar lists it will be equal to SPListTemplateType.Events.